# Does Windows will signal an event after wakeup?

Tags: windows, multithreading, winapi, network-programming

Recently I met a problem that my program seems waiting for an event handle and never return.

I call IcmpSendEcho2 to send ping request and have set the event parameter correctly. In normal situation if the ping response arrived or timeout the event handle should be singled by system. This works fine in most time but one day I found my program (some of the working threads) is halt after my computer wakes up from sleep state. I guess the root cause is that when the ping request is sent and before system signal the corresponding event handle then the system change to sleep state (no operation for a long time then laptop change to sleep state). After system wakes up by me the previous event handle got no chance to be singled.

Add the pseudo code is:

```
// a working thread
while (isWorking()) {
    ...
    IcmpSendEcho2(hIcmpFile, hEvent, NULL, NULL, ..., 5000/*timeout is 5 sec*/)
    ...
    WaitForsingleObject(hEvent, INFINITE); // hEvent should be signaled after
                                           // response arrived or timeout (5sec)
                                           // elapsed
                                           //
    ...
}
```

I don't know if I'm wrong. I'm still investigating on this problem and post this issue here hope somebody who has experience the same problem could help me. Thank you in advance!

Comment: It could be that the system when to sleep before it received the ICMP ping response. This means that the system never received the actual response and hence did not signal the event.

Comment: Yes, I agree with you. But this is just our guess. In addition, there are two conditions the event handle will be signaled, response arrived and timeout. So, the event should be signaled because of timeout although the response isn't be received.

Comment: What is the timeout interval? Can you add a code snippet of exactly what are you doing?

Comment: Maybe looking at RegisterPowerSettingNotification to receive a message on sleep change will help you to catch those errors.